# what is the best way to fix the size of the disc based cache ??android -volley

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

1)The default implementation of the disc based cache present in android -volley is allocated a total memory of 5MB .

2)But the app Iam developing contains a lot of images .So I want to increase the size of the memory allocated by disc based cache .

3)So I want to increase the size of the cache ..I can simple do it by changing the value of DEFAULT_DISK_USAGE_BYTES inside Diskbasedcache.java file .

4)But I want to allocate memory based on the amount of space available in the disc ???Is there any way to implement it ??

Answer (score 4):

Few thoughts about Volley cache:

Using a disk based L1 cache may cause i/o blocking issues. Volley already has an implicit disk L2 cache. *BitmapLruImageCache*  is a basic "least recently used" in memory cache implementation. It is fast and does not block I/O. This is the recommended approach.

I recommend you to play around this [L1 cache for Volley](https://github.com/rdrobinson3/VolleyImageCacheExample)

for tweaking the size have a look at this:

```
RequestQueue volleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
DiskBasedCache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 16 * 1024 * 1024);
volleyQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack()));
volleyQueue.start();
```

Ref: [Volley cache](https://raw2.github.com/yuvipanda/apps-android-commons/5224282caaaf66a993818d163d904b93eb27a1f0/commons/src/main/java/org/wikimedia/commons/CommonsApplication.java)
other ref about volley cache http://www.jayway.com/2013/10/04/image-caching-with-volley/

Comment: Hey ..Sorry I couldn't understand the difference between L1 and L2 cache ..The cache present in Diskbasedcache.java file  is L1 or L2??

Comment: @user2391218 use that code i displayed or Volley cache git link if you don't want learn theory part !

Comment: is 16 the max size? @LOG_TAG

Comment: @scheychan There is no per-application limit for the cache directory. for more  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175843/limit-size-of-cache-directory/2863141#2863141

Comment: Thanks @LOG_TAG , I think the answer helps