# out of memory issue with volley's disk cache

Tags: android, caching, memory, android-volley

In my app for Android I'm using Volley for loading images in custom listview.

when i refresh(delete all items and load tiems) listview many times,
my app is killed with this message

how can i fix it?

> 04-26 13:08:01.038: E/dalvikvm-heap(18040): Out of memory on a 1684947261-byte allocation.
>   04-26 13:08:01.038: I/dalvikvm(18040): "Thread-11094" prio=5 tid=299 RUNNABLE
>   04-26 13:08:01.038: I/dalvikvm(18040):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x439ea8e8 self=0x7fb55250
>   04-26 13:08:01.038: I/dalvikvm(18040):   | sysTid=18946 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=2102160344
>   04-26 13:08:01.038: I/dalvikvm(18040):   | state=R schedstat=( 109248225 27367764 57 ) utm=9 stm=1 core=2
>   04-26 13:08:01.038: I/dalvikvm(18040):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:~316)
>   04-26 13:08:01.038: I/dalvikvm(18040):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
>   04-26 13:08:01.038: I/dalvikvm(18040):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:549)
>   04-26 13:08:01.038: I/dalvikvm(18040):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
>   04-26 13:08:01.038: I/dalvikvm(18040):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
>   04-26 13:08:01.038: I/dalvikvm(18040):   at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: W/dalvikvm(18040): threadid=299: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41745da0)
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: I/SpenGestureManager(847): setFocusWindow0
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: D/PointerIcon(847): setHoveringSpenIconStyle1 pointerType: 10001iconType:1 flag:0
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: D/PointerIcon(847): setHoveringSpenCustomIcon IconType is same.1
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: E/AndroidRuntime(18040): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11094
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: E/AndroidRuntime(18040): Process: com.android.myapp, PID: 18040
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: E/AndroidRuntime(18040): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: E/AndroidRuntime(18040):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: E/AndroidRuntime(18040):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: E/AndroidRuntime(18040):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:549)
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: E/AndroidRuntime(18040):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: E/AndroidRuntime(18040):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
>   04-26 13:08:01.048: E/AndroidRuntime(18040):    at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:84)
>   04-26 13:08:01.058: W/ActivityManager(847):   Force finishing activity com.android.myapp/.feedlist.Feedlist

Comment: This question is almost 2 years old but I am still searching for a solution to it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095909/volley-out-of-memory-error-weird-allocation-attempt/24422376#comment54546831_24422376) is similar but the answer does not work for me. OP did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
RequestQueue volleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
DiskBasedCache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 16 * 1024 * 1024);
volleyQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack()));
volleyQueue.start();
```

from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21299261/3399432

This changes the cache size

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue with loading images into a ListView. It seems you have to handle pulling from the cache yourself.

Below is my implementation which I have in my `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` adapter method:

```
Bitmap cachedBitmap = imageCache.getBitmap(item.getPhotoUrl());
if (cachedBitmap != null)
{
    holder.photo.setImageBitmap(cachedBitmap);
}
else {
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context), imageCache);
    imageLoader.get(item.getPhotoUrl(), new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
            if (item.getPhotoUrl() != null && response.getBitmap() != null)
                imageCache.putBitmap(item.getPhotoUrl(), response.getBitmap());
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    //This is a custom imageview, you can create your own implementation for loading the image url to the imageview
    holder.photo.setImageUrl(item.getPhotoUrl(), imageLoader);
}
```