# Shared Preferences: Long Strings

Tags: android, preferences, shared

Is there a rule how much data can be saved as a value in shared preferences in Android. Is it possible to save for example Strings that are 1 GB large? I know that it would be better to use a file but at the time I don't need a "clean" implementation.

Comment: yes, you can save data how much large data it is. you question look like is there a limit for an app size? :) I think you got the ans

Comment: I don't know of any rule, but you definitely will cause OutOfMemory exception if you try to use a 1GB String (because all variables are kept in memory). You have to use some kind of InputStream.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any practical limitations to the SharedPref but just a few pointers.

The maximum size of a java String is

```
2^31-1 =about 2 billion characters or roughly 1.86GB
```

So there's a limitation to the storage in terms of the datatype itself.

Not to mention Android seems to load SharedPreferences once and subsequent ones work off the cache, so in terms of performance you would be screwing big time as this may definitely throw an exception.

```
It seems a disaster in the making.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a hard limit set. I use gson to store complex objects in SharedPreferences all the time without issue. Just make sure you dont take up all the device storage.

Comment: This seems a bit vague as OP mentioned its a pretty huge data ~1GB , I don't suppose this validates  your GSON dataset size.Besides droid caches the SharedPref so such a big string would definitely ause problems

Answer (score 1):

Store the file in the app directory as file,

1. You are better off without storing such data in preferences
2. You will free from cleanup process, if the app is uninstall, so is all the file, inside its package directory.

   To get Appdirectory use

   ```
      /**
       * Takes the context and gets the current app directory path
       * 
       * @param context
       * @return
       */
   private static String getAppDirectory(Context context) 
   {
       String appDirectory=null;
       try {
           appDirectory=context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
       } catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
       {
           ATZLog.e(TAG, "error while retriving app directory in getAppDirectory");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return appDirectory;
   }
   ```

Store your file in directory structure as

```
\com.yourpackage\bigfiles\1GbFile.ext
```

Nobody else can see or use it.

Also one thing out of practice, Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863141/1225413) about storing huge data in app directory
and also there might something odd with your design, if you have 1 gb string data