# Limit apps cache size in Android

Tags: android, caching, android-settings

Is there anyway to limit the cache size of a certain application in Android, not the entire OS cache?
I don't want to manually delete cache directory every time.

Comment: you mean you want to limit other apps cache size?

Comment: I just want to limit a specific app such as Firefox or Chrome Browser, preventing from swallowing my storage. For example, change Chrome cache size from infinite down to 50 MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863141/2101822

He said :

> There is no per-application limit for the cache directory.