# How large should the cachDirectory be?

Tags: android, caching

I am quite new to Android Application Development.
My app has is caching data in files. Now I want to limit the cache size but I have trouble to decide what value I should take. Are there standards or konventions for orientation?

Comment: That seems to depend entirely on your application.

Comment: Are there some limits or anything?

Comment: Depends if its memory cache or file caching

Comment: @MalekHijazi I write Jsons in files in the getExternalFilesDir so i guess file caching

Comment: @J.Doe file caching there is no limit as long there's enough storage space

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2863141/3327198

He said:

> There is no per-application limit for the cache directory.

Comment: jes but there should be I think. I have to control how much data I store in my files so that this app doesn´t slow down my device if I am not careful