# Is there a way to set a cache limit for my Android app?

Tags: android

I want to set a cache limit for my android app. My app is creating PNG files periodically and saving them to a folder on the phone it's installed on. I want it so if the folder hits this limit (10MB) it will automatically start deleting the files starting with the oldest ones deleting only a certain amount at a time (9MB). I also want this process to run in the background of the phone.

How do I do this? Screenshots would be *most* helpful. Thank you.

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.2. My app needs to work for Android 4.4.

Comment: There is no `C:\SysApp` directory on an Android device. `C:` is a Windows concept; Android is not Windows. If you really do mean a directory on an Android device (e.g., your app's `getCacheDir()`), use `JobScheduler` to occasionally check your directory size and perform the deletions.

Comment: Oops. I'm also trying to make a C# program and my brain just automatically put it in there. Sorry. Also, I read somewhere the `JobScheduler` is fairly new and only works with Android 5.0+. I forgot to mention my app needs to work on Android 4.4.

Comment: Use `AlarmManager` on Android 4.4. Or, use a library like Evernote's `android-job` library, that gives you a uniform API to work, where the library chooses the right scheduling engine based on API level.

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about using `AlarmManager`? I've heard a bit about it and read up on it some, but I don't quite understand how it works in terms of what command to type if that makes sense.

Comment: See [the developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). It should also be covered by whatever Android app development book you are using (e.g., [mine](https://commonsware.com/Android)).

Comment: Thank you. Also, I'm not using any book. I'm just kind of learning as I go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no per-application limit for the cache directory.

Look here : [Limit size of cache directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175843/limit-size-of-cache-directory/2863141#2863141)

Comment: What if it's just a limit for that app's directory it's created?